# awk using dynamic column number

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I would like to have a bash function that prints the specific column of a given string.

My solution works fine but it is verbose and looks ugly to me.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_ip_segment() {
    case "$2" in
        1)
            printf "%s" "$(echo $1 | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')"
            ;;
        2)
            printf "%s" "$(echo $1 | awk -F '.' '{print $2}')"
            ;;
        3)
            printf "%s" "$(echo $1 | awk -F '.' '{print $3}')"
            ;;
        4)
            printf "%s" "$(echo $1 | awk -F '.' '{print $4}')"
            ;;
        *)
            printf "%s" "$1"
            ;;
    esac
}

IP="12.34.56.78"
echo $IP

echo "$(get_ip_segment $IP 1)"
echo "$(get_ip_segment $IP 2)"
echo "$(get_ip_segment $IP 3)"
echo "$(get_ip_segment $IP 4)"
```

Output:

```
12.34.56.78
12
34
56
78
```

Then I tried to optimize this code by removing the `switch` structure, but it printed an unexpected output.

```
printf "%s" "$(echo $1 | awk -F '.' '{print column_id}' column_id=$2)"
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
```

But somehow, the variable substitution does not work correctly inside `awk`.
That could be great if I could have a one-line long function instead of this verbose one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surely do it like this:

```bash
get_ip_segment() {
   awk -F. -v c="$2" '{print 1<=c && c<=NF ? $c : $0}' <<<  "$1"
}

IP="12.34.56.78"

get_ip_segment "$IP" 1
12

get_ip_segment "$IP" 2
34

get_ip_segment "$IP" 3
56

get_ip_segment "$IP" 4
78

get_ip_segment "$IP"
12.34.56.78

get_ip_segment "$IP" 5
12.34.56.78
```

Comment: this condition`1<=c`, you can just check it once at `BEGIN { }`, and if it failed, set it to some ridiculously large number like `8^16` so it would always fail `c<=NF` (but this extra stuff is only worth it if the input might be more than a handful of rows)

Comment: Yes, nice optimizations !

Comment: thanks. if you wanna streamline it further, perhaps  :::::::: ::::::::::::::::: :::::::::: :::::::::::::::: ::::::::: ::::: :::::::::::::::: `{ print $((c <= NF) * c) }'` ::::::::: replacing the branching ternary with a multiplication

Comment: That's really cool !

Comment: keep the sarcasm

Answer (score 1):

In plain Bash:

```
get_ip_segment() {
    local output=$1
    if [[ $2 = [1-4] ]]; then
        local -a octets
        IFS=. read -ra octets <<< "$output"
        output=${octets[$2 - 1]}
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$output"
}

ip=12.34.56.78
get_ip_segment "$ip" 1
get_ip_segment "$ip" 2
get_ip_segment "$ip" 3
get_ip_segment "$ip" 4
get_ip_segment "$ip"
```

Or, in POSIX shell:

```
get_ip_segment() {
    case $2 in
        1) output=${1%%.*};;
        2) output=${1#*.}
           output=${output%%.*};;
        3) output=${1%.*}
           output=${output##*.};;
        4) output=${1##*.};;
        *) output=$1
    esac
    printf '%s\n' "$output"
}

ip=12.34.56.78
get_ip_segment "$ip" 1
get_ip_segment "$ip" 2
get_ip_segment "$ip" 3
get_ip_segment "$ip" 4
get_ip_segment "$ip"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any POSIX shell:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_ip_segment() { awk -v ip="$1" -v seg="$2" 'BEGIN{ split(ip,a,"."); print (seg in a ? a[seg] : ip) }'; }

ip=12.34.56.78
get_ip_segment "$ip" 1
get_ip_segment "$ip" 2
get_ip_segment "$ip" 3
get_ip_segment "$ip" 4
get_ip_segment "$ip" 0
get_ip_segment "$ip" 5
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
12
34
56
78
12.34.56.78
12.34.56.78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ip=12.34.56.78
$ get_ip_segment(){ cut -d. -f $2 <<<$1; }
$ for i in {1..4}; do get_ip_segment $ip $i; done
12
34
56
78
```